# Error in PowerShell script: Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'

Tags: powershell

I am struggling with an error message which shows up whenever I run the script below.
Could you please help me to identify and fix this error message?

Error message:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'

    At line:1 char:1
    + $success + $failed |
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

---

Here is full script:

```
$Header = @"
<style>
table {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
</style>
"@

$params = @{
    ComputerName  = Get-Content -Path 'C:\servers.txt'
    Count         =  1
    ErrorAction   = 'SilentlyContinue'
    ErrorVariable = 'errors'
}

$success = Test-Connection @params |
               Select-Object @{n='Server';e={$_.address}},
                             IPv4Address,
                             @{n='Result';e={'Successful'}}

$failed = $errors.exception.message |
              Where-Object {$_ -match "computer '(.+?)'"} |
                  Select-Object @{n='Server';e={$matches.1}},
                                @{n='IPv4Address';e={"N/A"}},
                                @{n='Result';e={'Failed'}}

    $success + $failed |
        ConvertTo-Html -Title "Fragment" -Head $Header |
            Set-Content -Path StatusReport.html -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: The error message pretty much describes the problem - there’s no defined meaning for “adding” two PSObjects. What is your expected result? Because you’ll need to find another way to achieve it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `$success + $failed`

*expectedly fails*, because these variables contain `[pscustomobject]` instances (full type name is `[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]`, as returned by the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) cmdlet:

**`[pscustomobject]` instances do not have an `op_addition` method,** as the error message indicates, which is the normally hidden method that **underlies the `+` operator.**

---

**In the event that `$success` is a *single object***, what you presumably want instead is:

```
$success, $failed | ConvertTo-Html ...
```

This sends both objects to `ConvertTo-Html` via the pipeline one by one, by constructing an array via `,` the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-), which the pipeline automatically enumerates.

**If, `$success` may *situationally* be either a *scalar* (single object) or an *array* of objects** - depending on whether `Test-Connection` returns one or multiple objects - **use `@()`**, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) to guarantee that `$success` is *always* treated as an array, which then allows you to **perform *array concatenation* with `+`** safely (see below):

```
@($success) + $failed | ConvertTo-Html ...
```

---

Note that **it is possible to *concatenate arrays* with `+`**, but **only if (at least) the LHS already is an array**. You can use the *unary* form of `,` to create a single-element array on demand, and applying `+` to that then concatenates the RHS to form a new array. Thus, the following statement is equivalent to the above:

```
# `, $success` construct a single-element array, and `+` then concatenates
# $failed to it (even though $failed is just a scalar), resulting in a (new)
# 2-element array.
, $success + $failed | ConvertTo-Html ...
```

Note that if the RHS is an array too, its elements are appended one by one (as opposed to appending the array as a whole as a single new element); e.g., `1, 2  +  3, 4` yields new array `1, 2, 3, 4`.